# Moq Returns not getting invoked

Tags: c#, .net, generics, moq

I have a class that receives an `ICacheManager` via injection:

```
public ClientIdToClientNameResolver(IDataManager<Client> clientManager, ICacheManager cacheManager, ILogUtils logUtils)
{
    this.clientManager = clientManager;
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    this.logUtils = logUtils;
}
```

There is a line of code that then executes the `Get` method on it:

```
var client = cacheManager
    .Get(CacheKeys.Clients, () => clientManager.Get())
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);
```

The signature for that method is:

```
TResult Get<TResult>(string key, Func<TResult> defaultValue = null)
```

That specific execution of `Get` has a `TResult` of `List<Client>` and so I'm mocking it up like this:

```
var cacheManagerMock = new Mock<ICacheManager>();
cacheManagerMock.Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<List<Client>>>()))
    .Returns(new List<Client>());
```

However, when executing the test, the call to:

```
var client = cacheManager
    .Get(CacheKeys.Clients, () => clientManager.Get())
```

is returning `null`. I know that because in a previous iteration I broke that statement out on its own. What did I do wrong with the `Mock`?

Comment: Probably because Moq fails to cast the return value of your `clientManager.Get()` to `List<Client>`. What does `clientManager.Get()` returns?

Comment: @haim770 so I tried getting explicit with it, based on your comment, and that failed too. I changed it to `.Get<List<Client>>(CacheKeys.Clients, () => clientManager.Get())`; is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Is `Get<TResult>` overloaded?  Also, if you're using loose mocks, try making them strict to see if a mock is not being set up correctly.

Comment: @ColinM, of course... that's how I *know* the call to `Get` is returning a `null` as stated in the last section of the question.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk, the method is not overloaded, but I did try making it more strict by adding the exact string it should receive and that didn't change anything. The `Func` is already as specific as it can get right?

Comment: @MikePerrenoud Yeah unfortunately the `Func` can't get any more specific.  And just to be clear, [mock strictness is an opt-in feature](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior).  Did you try that?

Comment: Oh, @PatrickQuirk, I've not tried doing that. That could be a very useful feature because at least it would throw an exception based on that documentation!

Comment: I'm not sure but are you sure that you are working against cacheManagerMock.Object

Comment: @MikePerrenoud what I meant by that was stepping through values to ensure you're working with the correct mocks, like BRAHIM has pointed toward

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel, yes it's leveraging the `Mock.Object` I created. I invoke that method with `PrivateObject`, so there is a couple other pieces of code I excluded that invoke that constructor.

Comment: could you reproduce the issue in a complete sample

Comment: @MikePerrenoud. Your first example makes use of `FirstOrDefault` linq expression. You setup the mock to return an empty list. Stands to reason that the first or default will return `null` when executed against an empty list.

Comment: @Nkosi, negative. I'm not worried about the return result from `FirstOrDefault`. As I stated *at the end of the question* I know the issue is with the `Get` returning `null` because *I broke that line out and stepped through it* and therefore the test is throwing a LINQ exception about the source being `null`.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud, Might i suggest providing a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. What I tried to too long for a comment so added as an answer. review and compare.

Answer (score 1):

The following [mcve] was used to try and reproduce the issue based on the original example provided.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest4 {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1() {
        //Arrange
        var clients = new List<Client>(){
            new Client { Id = 1 }
        };

        var cacheManagerMock = new Mock<ICacheManager>();
        cacheManagerMock
            .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<List<Client>>>()))
            .Returns(clients);

        var clientId = 1;
        var clientManager = Mock.Of<IDataManager<Client>>();
        var cacheManager = cacheManagerMock.Object;

        //Act
        var client = cacheManager
            .Get(CacheKeys.Clients, () => clientManager.Get())
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == clientId);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(client);
    }

    public class Client { public int Id { get; set; } }

    public interface ICacheManager {
        TResult Get<TResult>(string key, Func<TResult> defaultValue = null);
    }

    public interface IDataManager<T> {
        List<T> Get();
    }

    public class CacheKeys {
        public const string Clients = "FakeKey";
    }
}
```

However the test passes as expected.